# CUBA : edit action does not open expected screen

Tags: cuba-platform

I have:
- a Person browser screen which is the standard one
- a Person editor frame
- a Person editor screen which simply includes the Person editor frame

For some reason, when I open the editor from the browser, I'm facing a screen that is not the one I expect, and I did not design. The said screen seems to have been automatically generated on the fly.

The frame design (mapped to person-edit-frame.xml) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<window xmlns="http://schemas.haulmont.com/cuba/window.xsd"
    caption="msg://editCaption"
    class="com.busy.busyapp.gui.person.PersonEditFrame"
    messagesPack="com.busy.busyapp.gui.person">
<dsContext>
    <datasource id="personDs"
                class="com.busy.busyapp.entity.Person"
                view="person-view">
        <collectionDatasource id="phoneLinesDs"
                              property="phoneLines"/>
    </datasource>
</dsContext>
<layout expand="rootBox"
        spacing="true">
    <scrollBox id="rootBox"
               spacing="true">
        <vbox id="details"
              spacing="true">
            <fieldGroup id="typeFieldGroup"
                        datasource="personDs">
                <column width="250px">
                    <field id="type"
                           custom="true"/>
                </column>
            </fieldGroup>
            <fieldGroup id="titleFieldGroup"
                        datasource="personDs">
                <column width="250px">
                    <field id="title"
                           custom="true"/>
                </column>
            </fieldGroup>
            <fieldGroup id="positionFieldGroup"
                        datasource="personDs">
                <column width="250px">
                    <field id="position"
                           custom="true"/>
                </column>
            </fieldGroup>
            <fieldGroup id="nameFieldGroup"
                        datasource="personDs">
                <column width="250px">
                    <field id="name"/>
                </column>
                <column width="250px">
                    <field id="firstName"/>
                </column>
            </fieldGroup>
        </vbox>
        <groupBox id="phoneLinesBox"
                  caption="msg://com.busy.busyapp.entity/Person.phoneLines">
            <table id="phoneLinesTable"
                   height="200px"
                   width="100%">
                <actions>
                    <action id="add"
                            openType="DIALOG"/>
                    <action id="remove"/>
                </actions>
                <columns>
                    <column id="label"/>
                    <column id="number"/>
                </columns>
                <rows datasource="phoneLinesDs"/>
                <buttonsPanel>
                    <button action="phoneLinesTable.add"
                            icon="font-icon:PLUS"/>
                    <button action="phoneLinesTable.remove"
                            icon="font-icon:MINUS"/>
                </buttonsPanel>
            </table>
        </groupBox>
    </scrollBox>
    <frame id="windowActions"
           screen="extendedEditWindowActions"/>
</layout>
```

The screen embedding the frame (mapped to person-edit.xml) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<window xmlns="http://schemas.haulmont.com/cuba/window.xsd"
    caption="msg://editCaption"
    class="com.busy.busyapp.gui.person.PersonEdit"
    datasource="personDs"
    messagesPack="com.busy.busyapp.gui.person">
<dsContext>
    <datasource id="personDs"
                class="com.busy.busyapp.entity.Person"
                view="person-view">
        <collectionDatasource id="phoneLinesDs"
                              property="phoneLines"/>
    </datasource>
</dsContext>
<layout spacing="true">
    <label id="toto"
           datasource="personDs"
           property="id"/>
    <frame screen="busyapp$Person.edit.frame"/>
    <scrollBox height="100px"
               spacing="true"/>
    <frame id="windowActions"
           screen="extendedEditWindowActions"/>
</layout>
```

The screen I get :

[image: screen 2]

Edit : screens.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<screen-config xmlns="http://schemas.haulmont.com/cuba/screens.xsd">
<screen id="busyapp$Customer.browse"
        template="com/busy/busyapp/gui/customer/customer-browse.xml"/>
<screen id="busyapp$Customer.edit"
        template="com/busy/busyapp/gui/customer/customer-edit.xml"/>
<screen id="busyapp$ImpBusyArticles.browse"
        template="com/busy/busyapp/gui/impbusyarticles/impbusyarticles-browse.xml"/>
<screen id="busyapp$ImpBusyArticles.edit"
        template="com/busy/busyapp/gui/impbusyarticles/impbusyarticles-edit.xml"/>
<screen id="busyapp$Product.browse"
        template="com/busy/busyapp/gui/product/product-browse.xml"/>
<screen id="busyapp$Product.edit"
        template="com/busy/busyapp/gui/product/product-edit.xml"/>
<screen id="busyapp$ProductFamily.browse"
        template="com/busy/busyapp/gui/productfamily/product-family-browse.xml"/>
<screen id="busyapp$ProductFamily.edit"
        template="com/busy/busyapp/gui/productfamily/product-family-edit.xml"/>
<screen id="busyapp$Provider.browse"
        template="com/busy/busyapp/gui/provider/provider-browse.xml"/>
<screen id="busyapp$Provider.edit"
        template="com/busy/busyapp/gui/provider/provider-edit.xml"/>
<screen id="busyapp$Stock.browse"
        template="com/busy/busyapp/gui/stock/stock-browse.xml"/>
<screen id="busyapp$Stock.edit"
        template="com/busy/busyapp/gui/stock/stock-edit.xml"/>
<screen id="busyapp$VatRate.browse"
        template="com/busy/busyapp/gui/vatrate/vat-rate-browse.xml"/>
<screen id="busyapp$VatRate.edit"
        template="com/busy/busyapp/gui/vatrate/vat-rate-edit.xml"/>
<screen id="busyapp$SalePrice.browse"
        template="com/busy/busyapp/gui/saleprice/sale-price-browse.xml"/>
<screen id="busyapp$SalePrice.edit"
        template="com/busy/busyapp/gui/saleprice/sale-price-edit.xml"/>
<screen id="busyapp$SupplyPrice.browse"
        template="com/busy/busyapp/gui/supplyprice/supply-price-browse.xml"/>
<screen id="busyapp$SupplyPrice.edit"
        template="com/busy/busyapp/gui/supplyprice/supply-price-edit.xml"/>
<screen id="busyapp$Person.browse"
        template="com/busy/busyapp/gui/person/person-browse.xml"/>
<screen id="busyapp$Person.edit"
        template="com/busy/busyapp/gui/person/person-edit.xml"/>
<screen id="busyapp$Order.browse"
        template="com/busy/busyapp/gui/order/order-browse.xml"/>
<screen id="busyapp$Order.edit"
        template="com/busy/busyapp/gui/order/order-edit.xml"/>
<screen id="busyapp$Invoice.browse"
        template="com/busy/busyapp/gui/invoice/invoice-browse.xml"/>
<screen id="busyapp$Invoice.edit"
        template="com/busy/busyapp/gui/invoice/invoice-edit.xml"/>
<screen id="busyapp$Person.edit.frame"
        template="com/busy/busyapp/gui/person/person-edit-frame.xml"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [standard actions](https://doc.cuba-platform.com/manual-6.2/list_actions.html) use the following convention when selecting screens to open:

- `{entity_name}.edit` for opening an editor screen
- `{entity_name}.lookup` and `{entity_name}.browse` for opening a lookup screen

In your case, the browser by default opens the `yournamespace$Person.edit` screen. You can specify a screen to open for any action using the `setWindowId()` method.

Take a look at your `screens.xml` file to find out what screens are registered with what identifiers. The same information is available in the list of screens in Studio.

Comment: I knew that, this is what I was puzzled. But finally got it. For the record : I had duplicates screens with same ids in GUI and Web modules. The screen in Web module is what I see, It seems it has priority over GUI in case of name clash. BTW, it would be nice in "generate screens" feature that the default value for module could be changed, it is Web by default and my project is mostly GUI. Each time I generate screens I have to change it, and this time through my tests I made a mistake.

Comment: @Mike Yes, web screens have a priority because by default the web-screens.xml includes screens.xml from GUI and hence overrides it. We'll check how Studio works with screens having same Ids in different modules, perhaps it should be more clear for the developer. Also, we'll add the selection of default module for generating standard screens to the project settings - thanks for the hint.

Comment: Thanks Konstantin. For the priority a simple notice in the doc is enough in my eyes. However for the choice of default value for module type I go along, in my case it saves clicks, and I love when a feature saves clicks from me ;-)